# Ruby search by parent using child object OR search on parent using child ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a set-up where `Charge` HABTM `Item` via a `item_id` attribute, I'm trying to figure out which query would be faster:

```
a = Charge.where(item_id: 1).where(type:"test")
b = Item.find(id:1).charges.where(type:"test")
```

I feel like `a` is probably faster since you only have to look at one table, but interested in actual answer.

Comment: You could probably find out which one is faster yourself in the rails console ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right:
`a` is much faster as it only runs one SQL statement on one table.

`b` does something total different:

- it searches and instantiates one object of type `Item` (`Item.find(id:1)`)
- in a second step it uses the association `charges` to query a list of `Charges` that is equivalent (acutally identical) to the query in `a`

so obviously (without using `benchmark`:-) ), `a` is a true subset of `b` and therefore faster.

On the other hand: `b` is more object oriented, more general. So if for any reason the association between Items and Charges is not RoR standard (i.e. you have to use a different forreign key), `b` will still work while `a` has to be adjusted.

One of the examples where generalisation costs some speed.

Answer (score 1):

Running [benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) once makes absolutely no sense, benchmark is to be run at least as many times as the resulting execution time is more than 1s (to get rid of side effects, like accidental HDD latency, or whatever.)

Unfortunately, just running the benchmark in a loop—as is—does not make sense either, because of rails cache. So, the correct answer would probably be: “one should disable any rails cache and run benchmarks thousands times in a loop.” The easiest way to disable any rails cache in default configuration is to set the environment variable `RAILS_ENV=development` before execution.

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 50000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { n.times { Charge.where(item_id: 1).where(type:"test") } }
  x.report { n.times { Item.find(id:1).charges.where(type:"test") } }
end
```

But I would go with `ActiveRecord#to_sql` method. You might print out both queries, that rails builds to be executed against DB, and examine the pure SQL printed. In your case they would be pretty much the same (I am not sure and I can not test it right now due to the lack of environment, but I hope you get the point.)

```
  puts Charge.where(item_id: 1).where(type:"test").to_sql
  puts Item.find(id:1).charges.where(type:"test").to_sql
```

Hope it helps.